# Except block throwing SyntaxError

Tags: python, syntax, except

I am getting a syntax error for the except 
I read a lot of other answers, and i tried commenting out everything but the while loop to make sure it wasn't something else. Not sure what's up.

```
from timeit import default_timer

start = default_timer()

while True:
    print('a')
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        break
print(default_timer() - start)
```

Comment: Why are you using try-except without knowing the syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have no accompanying try statement with your exception catch

```
from timeit import default_timer

start = default_timer()

while True:
    try:
        print('a')
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        break
print(default_timer() - start)
```

Here are the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) on handling exceptions